# Compare multiple values in one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, loops, object

I need some help determining how i can compare 4 columns of one row with 4 columns of another row.

To explain, I have two tables, which both have four columns: State, Area, City & Location.

PINPOINT table - this table has a unique combination of values

FEED table - this table has a recurring combination of values, as well as the KEY value from the PINPOINT Table.

What i want is a code that says

"If a row from column CL in the FEED sheet contains the Key Value from column K in the PINPOINT sheet,

...but columns CN to CQ that FEED sheet row doesn't have the same values as column A-D in the PINPOINT table...

update column CN to CQ the FEED sheet with the same combination of values as A-D in the PINPOINT table."

I pasted the latest code i have below, as well as the images. Admittedly, this code is a mess I just started learning code, so I'm happy to rewrite this if someone proposes a solution.

In any case, any insight into how i should write this will be quite helpful.

```
var Data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // DATA spreadsheet

  var PinpointDataSheet = Data.getSheetByName("The Pinpoints") // DATA "Pinpoint" sheet
  var PinpointAllValues = PinpointDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, PinpointDataSheet.getLastRow()-1,PinpointDataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();


  var FeedDataSheet = Data.getSheetByName("The Feed_Raw") // DATA "Feed" sheet
  var FeedAllValues = FeedDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, FeedDataSheet.getLastRow()-1,FeedDataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var PinpointStateObj = {}; // Object for "Locale" values
  var PinpointAreaObj = {}; // Object for "Locale" values
  var PinpointCityObj = {}; // Object for "Locale" values
  var PinpointSpotObj = {}; // Object for "Locale" values

  for(var P = PinpointAllValues.length-1;P>=0;P--) // put Pinpoint values in array..

  {
    PinpointStateObj[PinpointAllValues[P][0]] = PinpointAllValues[P][10]; 
    PinpointAreaObj[PinpointAllValues[P][1]] = PinpointAllValues[P][10]; 
    PinpointCityObj[PinpointAllValues[P][2]] = PinpointAllValues[P][10];
    PinpointSpotObj[PinpointAllValues[P][3]] = PinpointAllValues[P][10]; 
  }

  for(var F = FeedAllValues.length-1;F>=0;F--) // for each row in the "Feed" sheet...
  { 
   var Feed_GeotagKey = FeedAllValues[F][90]; // Pinpoint Key values in Feed sheet
    {
      // If Pinpoint array dont match feed values
      if ((PinpointStateObj[Feed_GeotagKey] != FeedAllValues[F][95]) || (PinpointAreaObj[Feed_GeotagKey] != FeedAllValues[F][96]) 
        || (PinpointCityObj[Feed_GeotagKey] != FeedAllValues[F][97]) || (PinpointSpotObj[Feed_GeotagKey] != FeedAllValues[F][97]))
        {
        FeedAllValues[F][95] = PinpointAllValues[P][0]; // ...Change FYI Category Name in FYI Topic Sheet 
        FeedAllValues[F][96] = PinpointAllValues[P][1];
        FeedAllValues[F][97] = PinpointAllValues[P][2];
        FeedAllValues[F][98] = PinpointAllValues[P][3];

      }
    }
  }
```

[Geotag Sheet - unique values "Dark column"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UggnZ.png)
[Feed Sheet - recurring values - "Highlighted column"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywjgb.png)

Comment: @JohnG  To answer your specific question, the Feed table has over 2500 rows, and I don't expect them to change often. I feel automatically updating the four fields every time would unnecessarily prolong sync time. The condition I mentioned above is to check if the fields don't match before updating.

Comment: @JohnG ok, fair enough. I'll remove the check in my future code. I still need advice on the actual code, however. The code would have to see if the Pinpoint Key in the Feed sheet matches a value in PinPoint columns, then insert those exact values into the Feed sheet. The code I created is likely not optimal for that operation. Any ideas there?

Comment: @JohnG Re: OK. to explain. I'm using Javascript for Google Sheet. Pinpoint sheet has a row of 4 column values (ex: A,D,E,Q), along with a Key value (ex: key8) to identify each combination. The Feed sheet has that 4 column combination (A,D,E,Q) appearing in multiple rows, along with the Pinpoint key value (ex: key8). I need a loop function that says "if key8) is in the Feed sheet, but the referenced values are not (A,D,E,Q) use columns from the Pinpoint sheet (key8) row to transfer (A,D,E,Q) over make them match" . My question is how can I compare values from 4 different columns in the loop.

Comment: @JohnG Essentially this is just a basic loop function to update mismatched fields. My issue is that i don't know the best way to compare 4 different cells simultaneously with another. That is my ultimate question. As i mentioned in my previous post, that you initially disagreed with, is that i have to loop through all the rows to determine which combination is which (this cannot be avoided). I'm using the "if" to make it skip updating if they do not match. as far as why it's setup like this explaining that would make this post much more complicated than it seems you want it to be.

Comment: Lastly i did mention in my post that I'm new to coding. I know it's messy and complicated, which i why i asked the question on here in the first place. The answer is complicated because the question is complicated. But i was hoping for insight to solve this problem. You mentioned I can do this in one loop. Even writing (or providing a link to) example code that will do that will help me in this predicament. But I'll use your comments to modify my question and code, then make a new post, as it seems i won't get help here.